# 301 Redirect a directory only if there is no subdirectory / page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to create a 301 redirect using .HTACCESS file from a root of a directory to another:

> www.domain.com/source/?var=1 ----> www.domain.com/target/?var=1

but NOT if there if the url contains any page or subdirectory:

> www.domain.com/source/pretty_page/?var=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^source/?$ /target [L,NC,R=301]
```